# mapply with list and vector

Tags: r, mapply

Say I have a list with 3 elements -- each being a data frame --, a vector with 3 elements, and I want to apply a function to each element of the list and its respective element in the vector. Of course I could do this with a loop, but I am trying to vectorize it with `mapply`. Here's what I am doing

```
myList = list(data.frame(x = 1:10), data.frame(x = 1:5), data.frame(x = 6:1))
myVec = c(7, 1, 9)
myFun = function(x, y) {
    x$number = y
    return(x)
} 
res = mapply(myFun, myList, myVec)
```

`res` is NOT what I expected:

```
str(res)
List of 6
 $ : int [1:10] 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
 $ : num [1:10] 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7
 $ : int [1:5] 1 2 3 4 5
 $ : num [1:5] 1 1 1 1 1
 $ : int [1:6] 6 5 4 3 2 1
 $ : num [1:6] 9 9 9 9 9 9
 - attr(*, "dim")= int [1:2] 2 3
 - attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
  ..$ : chr [1:2] "x" "number"
  ..$ : NULL
```

what I expected was a list with three elements, each being a data frame with two columns, like so:

```
str(expected)
List of 3
 $ :'data.frame':   10 obs. of  2 variables:
  ..$ x     : int [1:10] 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
  ..$ number: num [1:10] 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7
 $ :'data.frame':   5 obs. of  2 variables:
  ..$ x     : int [1:5] 1 2 3 4 5
  ..$ number: num [1:5] 1 1 1 1 1
 $ :'data.frame':   6 obs. of  2 variables:
  ..$ x     : int [1:6] 6 5 4 3 2 1
  ..$ number: num [1:6] 9 9 9 9 9 9
```

what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
res = mapply(myFun, myList, myVec, SIMPLIFY = FALSE)
```

Answer (score 2):

We can use `Map`

```
Map(myFun, myList, myVec)
```

which uses by `default` `SIMPLIFY=FALSE` i.e.

```
Map
```

> ```
> function (f, ...)  {
> f <- match.fun(f)
> mapply(FUN = f, ..., SIMPLIFY = FALSE) 
> }
> ```